# Are those limits right?

Tags: limits, hyperbolic-functions

This is the answer of a problem in my quantum mechanics textbook, but I don't understand why the limits aren't equal to zero. Is this just the first term of a series expansion (in which case would be an approximation, and not a limit)?

[image]

Comment: Could it be that they don't actually mean _limit_, but rather are applying small number approximations? Because it's well-known that for small $x$, we have $\sinh^2(x) \approx \sin^2(x)\approx x^2$.

Comment: Yes, that is just first order approximation.

Comment: Sloppy notation...